# angularjs app.service(...) causes "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: angularjs

What worked well in former projects causes an error in the current project.
I have a couple of services for various tasks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service('test1', function() {
        return {
            sayHello : function() {
                 return ("Hello!");
            }
        };  
    })
    .service('test2', function() { //this line causes the error
        return {
            sayHi : function() {
                 return ("Hi!");
            }
        };
    })
    .service('test3', function() {
        ...
    })
```

When I include this file in my project I get the following error message in the line with the ".service('test2', function()...":

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Whatever I am doing - the 2nd method always causes this error. Looks like the first service method does not return an object? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found out what's the problem. I am working on an application which was started by someone else (CLIP-TWO Theme), who defined all services as providers in his router configuration file. That goes like this:

```
app.service = $provide.service;
```

When I now define my services the first one will work but the second one won't, because the second one is not in app scope but in provider scope.
So I had to change my service definition like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp'); // this is already done in the main js.
// define all services separately
app.service('test1', function() {...});
app.service('test2', function() {...});
app.service('test3', function() {...});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing some closing brackets, so the error that seems to be happening in the second service is actually being caused by a syntax error in the first service.

Try this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.service('test1', function() {
    return {
        sayHello : function() {
             return ("Hello!");
        }
    };      
})
.service('test2', function() {
    return {
        sayHi : function() {
             return ("Hi!");
        }
    };      
});
```

Comment: Thank you - I changed my sample. I am sorry, the real code has no missing brackets. It's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare service methods with this.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('test1', function() {
    this.sayHello = function() {
        return 'Hello';  
  };    
});
```